# Why Worker is not defined in js

Tags: javascript, html, web-worker

I wrote 3 files to test WebWorker,
**webworker.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="table"></table>
    <script>
        // var worker = new Worker('webworker3.1.js');
        var worker = new Worker('webworker3.1.js');
        worker.postMessage('');
        worker.onmessage = function(event){
            console.log(event.data);
            if(event.data != ''){
                var j, k, tr, td,
                    intArray = event.data.split(';'),
                    table = document.getElementById('table');
                for(var i = 0; i < intArray.length; i++){
                    j = parseInt(i / 10, 0);
                    k = i % 10;
                    if(k == 0){
                        tr = document.createElement('tr');
                        tr.id = 'tr' + j;
                        table.appendChild(tr);
                    }else{
                        tr = document.getElementById('tr' + j);
                    }
                    td = document.createElement('td');
                    tr.appendChild(td);
                    td.innerHTML = intArray[j * 10 + k];
                    td.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
                    td.style.color = 'white';
                    td.width = '30';
                }
            }
        };
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

this is a main html to show.

**webworker3.1.js**

```
onmessage = function(event){
    var intArray = new Array(100);
    for(var i = 0; i < 100; i++){
        intArray[i] = parseInt(Math.random() * 100);
    }
    var worker = new Worker('webworker3.2.js');
    worker.postMessage(JSON.stringify(intArray));
    worker.onmessage = function(event){
        postMessage(event.data);
    }       
}
```

this is the main thread, I create a child thread in it.
**webworker3.2.js**

```
onmessage = function(event){
    var intArray = JSON.parse(event.data);
    var returnStr = '';
    for(var i = 0; i < intArray.length; i++){
        if(parseInt(intArray[i] % 3) == 0){
            if('' !== returnStr){
                returnStr += ';';
            }
            returnStr += intArray[i];
        }
    }
    postMessage(returnStr);
    close();
}
```

When I open webworker.html in Chrome, it has a error:

```
webworker3.1.js:7 Uncaught ReferenceError: Worker is not defined
```

I can't find the reason, who can tell me?

Comment: What is the version of your chrome?

Answer (score 2):

Google Chrome has a known bug about nested workers, probably it hasn't been corrected yet; see this for more infos:

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=31666

Comment: Think you, I run it on IE and it ok